# MongoDB Add Fields Depends on Name?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.getCollection("user").aggregate([
   { $match : { fname : "test1" } },
   { $addFields: { email_address : "test1@gmail.com" } },
   { $match : { fname : "test2" } },
   { $addFields: { email_address : "test2@gmail.com" } }
])
```

I just want to add email address depends on fname value.
This code works only when there's no test2 so works once but don't repeat.
is there any ways I can repeat match and addfields?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$switch` for your case.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "email_address": {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            {
              "case": {
                $eq: [
                  "$fname",
                  "test1"
                ]
              },
              "then": "test1@gmail.com"
            },
            {
              "case": {
                $eq: [
                  "$fname",
                  "test2"
                ]
              },
              "then": "test2@gmail.com"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uOBYAL7bXSl) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the generalized case (in case it is applicable):

```
db.getCollection("user").aggregate([
   { $addFields: { email_address : {$concat: ["$fname", "@gmail.com"]} }}
])
```